# Engine oil change interval

Tags: engine, oil-change, scheduled-maintenance, drain, service-intervals

Very confusing topic I want to know exact drain interval of engine oil  company says 6000 km and my mechanic says every 2000 . I use semi synthetic veedol take off 4t 10w30 api sn in my hero honda CBZ xtreme (2014) . If I switch to 10w40 will be any issues please help me out . Please answer

Comment: Send a sample for analysis, then change if advised. If not follow manufacturer guidelines.

Comment: 2000km is a VERY short oil change interval.  What do Honda (or Honda Hero) recommend?

Comment: They recommend 10w30

Comment: 6000 km sounds about right for 10w30 oil. If your mechanic is suggesting every 2000 km then it's possible they're masking a larger symptom and you should be asking yourself "Why is my oil getting dirty so fast?". Just don't ask that question to your current mechanic because it sounds like they are  content with ripping you off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the recommended interval from your mechanic and the recommended interval from the oil manufacturer. But you are missing the number that you should start with - the one from *vehicle manufacturer*. If your vehicle came with a user manual, it's generally in the preventive maintenance section in that manual; if you don't have the manual, look online for your make & model.

Oil change intervals frequently specify both distance and time (e.g., "every 3000 miles or 3 months, whichever comes first"). 2000 kilometers is on the low side, but if you don't drive long distances, it may be an appropriate interval.

Comment: Please describe in detail what actually logic is behind frequent oil change or earlier then manufacturers recommended. Very confused on this topic tell me correct interval like km and months for change it